# X service wont start

Tags: 12.04

how to start x server? my display shows a flashing cursor. When i go to terminal (tty1) and call startx it just open graphical interface (where is what i want) but without menu bars without requiring to login.

What is going on? is the X server down?

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please be a bit more specific: When did i work the last time, what did you do before it stopped working?

Comment: What do yon need - just the X server? From what you describe, you are running the X server just fine with startx. But nothing more.

Comment: thank you. i was edited grub file (/etc/default grub) but i restore it. i also changed X11 file xorg.conf but i also restore it. but it doesn't made any difference.

Comment: i need my computer when it start ups, to load x server normally, with login etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. Finally. The problem is that i reinstalled lightdm and unity, and it was missing file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
so i executed:

```
#cat > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=true
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=
greeter-session=unity-gretter
user-session=ubuntu
```